# MySQL Router daemon not listening any ports

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-18.04, mysqlrouter

I installed the program as described here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-router/8.0/en/mysql-router-deploying-bootstrapping.html.

After installation, the service `mysqlrouter` was launched in the system. But this service does not listen any of the ports specified in the configuration file "/etc/mysqlrouter/mysqlrouter.conf".

Command `lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN` shows:

```
systemd-r 780 systemd-resolve 13u IPv4 17461 0t0 TCP 127.0.0.53:53 (LISTEN) 
sshd 1140 root 3u IPv4 20873 0t0 TCP *:22 (LISTEN) 
sshd 1140 root 4u IPv6 20890 0t0 TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
```

As you can see, only port 22 is listening.

To make the mysqlrouter listen to the port which defined in config file, I have to start it as a new process, using command `mysqlrouter -c /etc/mysqlrouter/mysqlrouter.conf &`.

After that, mysqlrouter listening the port and all is OK.

This is looks like that the service does not load the configuration file `/etc/mysqlrouter/mysqlrouter.conf` during startup, and uses default (empty) configuration, which not listening anything.

Configuration file contents:

```
[routing:default]
bind_address=0.0.0.0
bind_port=3306
destinations=metadata-cache://personal/default?role=PRIMARY
routing_strategy=first-available
protocol=classic
```

How to make mysqlrouter daemon start working in accordance with the configuration file, and listen on the specified ports?

If I start mysqlrouter as a new process using command `mysqlrouter -c /etc/mysqlrouter/mysqlrouter.conf &` it works properly:

```
systemd-r  780 systemd-resolve   13u  IPv4  17461      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.53:53 (LISTEN)
sshd      1140            root    3u  IPv4  20873      0t0  TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
sshd      1140            root    4u  IPv6  20890      0t0  TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
main      3615            root    4u  IPv4  43469      0t0  TCP *:3306 (LISTEN)
```

**Updated...**

Command `systemctl status mysqlrouter.service` shows:

```
● mysqlrouter.service - LSB: Start / Stop MySQL Router
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/mysqlrouter; generated)
   Active: active (exited) since Sun 2019-06-30 16:49:14 UTC; 2min 48s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 4089 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/mysqlrouter stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 4117 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/mysqlrouter start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Jun 30 16:49:14 webservicepersonal2o systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Start / Stop MySQL Router...
Jun 30 16:49:14 webservicepersonal2o mysqlrouter[4117]:  * Starting MySQL Router
Jun 30 16:49:14 webservicepersonal2o mysqlrouter[4117]:    ...done.
Jun 30 16:49:14 webservicepersonal2o systemd[1]: Started LSB: Start / Stop MySQL Router.
```

As I said, service works, but it still does not listening ports.

```
systemd-r  780 systemd-resolve   13u  IPv4  17461      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.53:53 (LISTEN)
sshd      1140            root    3u  IPv4  20873      0t0  TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
sshd      1140            root    4u  IPv6  20890      0t0  TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
```

Comment: You say the service is running but don't provide any actual output that actually shows it. Please stop your terminal mysqlrouter service and do a `systemctl start mysqlrouter.service && systemctl status mysqlrouter.service`

Comment: @AlexandreJuma it does not work either. The service has been started, but port 3306 is not listening.

Comment: Please update your question with the output of `systemctl status mysqlrouter.service`.

Comment: Thanks, can you check `/var/log/mysqlrouter` or `/var/log/messages` for any strange messages? System is not monitoring your process (Active: active (exited)) for some reason. Also please check if the process is running with `ps -ef | grep mysqlrouter`

Comment: @AlexandreJuma when I start/restart service mysqlrouter.log empty at all. Your command for process check says "root      4419  4171  0 17:44 pts/1    00:00:00 grep --color=auto mysqlrouter" (color actually red).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195771/discussion-between-vladimir-and-alexandre-juma).

Answer (score 0):

Use the following instead.

```
bind_address=127.0.0.1
```

I got the following:

```
netstat -ntlp
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      6117/mysqlrouter
```

Use `dbhost: 127.0.0.1`

Answer (score 0):

Using this command is normal.

try this:

```
sudo mysqlrouter --user=mysqlrouter --bootstrap root@192.168.30.241:3306  --conf-use-sockets  --report-host localhost  --force
```